# Where predicate and Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda

I have this line of code that returns index of particular object in a `IList<T>`

```
int index = list.IndexOf(list.Where(x => x.Code == searchValue).FirstOrDefault());
```

and I have similar construction on many places, which searches collections on different properties. My goal is to automate this, so I can have a generic method `MyClass<T>`

```
int index = myClass.Find<T>(x=> x.Code == searchValue);
```

or

```
int index = MyClass.Find<T>(x => x.Name.ToUpper().StartsWith(searchValue.ToUpper()));
```

Is this possible with Lambda expressions?

### Edit:

For anyone that is asking the same, here is the code that is working:

```
public int Find(Func<T, bool> whereClause)
{
    return _list.IndexOf(_list.Where<T>(whereClause).FirstOrDefault<T>());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think you need to use an expression tree. Assuming `list` is a `List<T>`, you should be able to use [`FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx):

```
int index = list.FindIndex(x => x.Code == searchValue);
```

If that's *not* what you need, please give us more information about what the types involved are.

Comment: Thanks John, I am exploring the world of Linq and Lambda expressions, so I am trying to understand how to works.

Comment: @Goran: It's worth bearing in mind that they're separate things. Lambda expressions can be converted into expression trees or delegates, whether or not you're using LINQ.

Comment: Thanks, John, I will need to read more, its jut that I like to work with code first, and see where can I come without too much theory. :) How can I accept your answer, if I am able to do this at all? :)

Comment: @Goran: You should be able to just click on the "tick" box to the left of my answer.